# Is it possible to attribute an int to a String in java?

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to attribute a number to a String in java with an assignment(?) expression?

Let's say that we have:

```
String strA = "Hello"; 
String strB = "Hi";
```

Can we somehow associate 1 to strA and 2 to strB to later convert the Strings into each other by using arithmetic operations?

edit: This question is not a duplicate of the suggested link because my strings do not have numbers in it, and I want to keep the string for later use so I was  not looking for some kind of typecasting method.

Comment: what do you mean by "convert the Strings into each other by using arithmetic operations"?

Comment: `String[] ab = {"Hello", "Saluton"}; ...: s = s.replace(ab[0], ab[1]);` Arrays might help.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you are asking for a **mapping** function.

The most easy way would be to use `List<String> mappedStrings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "Hi");`

Now you can get to "Hello" via `mappedStrings.get(0)` for example (und using index 1, you get to "Hi").

In other words: using a list, you get an *implicit* mapping using the order of elements in that list.

If you need something more generic (maybe when the numbers aren't consecutive), the natural choice would be use a `Map<Integer, String>` instead of a plain List:

```
Map<Integer, String> stringsById = new HashMap<>();
stringsById.put(1, "Hello");
stringsById.put(2, "Hi");
stringsById.put(42, "Hallo");
```

From there: you might even need some **two way** mapping, or slightly different, have something like `Map<Integer, List<String>>`. Meaning: if the idea is that different strings represent the "same" information, you might want to associate them to the *same* id somehow.

Comment: I assume you meant to write `List<String> mappedStrings`?

Answer (score 0):

To extend the map approach of the other answer:
To assign a value to the String you want to use a `Map` of some sort.

```
HashMap <String, Int> map = new HashMap();
map.put("Hello", 1);
map.put("Hi", 2);
```